# VBA code to look for all amount greater than 0 then consider all unique values from another column

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, unique

I'm trying to build a code that looks like this:

```
If column D > 0 then consider all unique values from column B 
and put the values in cell "A1"
```

The problem is that Column B has duplicated values and I just want the unique values that are greater then 0 in Column E.

Example of the worksheet

[image]
Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Do you mean if the value in a *cell* in column D is greater than `0` then take the corresponding value in column `B`? If yes, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51903740/edit) your question and clarify accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array to process faster and dictionary to select distinct values.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetDistinctValuesBasedOnCondition()
    Dim inputArray(), distinctList As Object, currentItem As Long, outputString As String
    Const BASE_STRING As String = "Output: "
    Set distinctList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        inputArray = .Range("B4:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
        For currentItem = LBound(inputArray, 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)
            If Not distinctList.Exists(Replace$(inputArray(currentItem, 1), Chr$(32), vbNullString)) And inputArray(currentItem, 3) > 0 Then
                distinctList.Add Replace$(inputArray(currentItem, 1), Chr$(32), vbNullString), 1
                outputString = outputString & inputArray(currentItem, 1) & ", "
            End If
        Next
        If Len(outputString) > 0 Then .Range("A1") = BASE_STRING & Left$(outputString, InStrRev(outputString, ", ") - 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you so much!! Perfect!

Comment: Hi Qharr, whenever there is no duplicated values, for some reason the "Output:" it says "Grade" instead of empty or blank.

Comment: Even if everything on column D is 0 or blank, it shows "Grade" on the Output.. like "Output: Grade".

Comment: Just checked one thing, it keeps the first line, whatever title it is.

Comment: Is your data as shown in the image? If all values in column D from row 4 down are zero, nothing is output.

Comment: You are correct Qharr, thank you once again I'm apologies.

Comment: Hi QHarr, I found out what I was doing wrong, I added one extra column with numbers between Title and Amount and the query and it was giving the unique value for that new column.

I tried on changing the inputarray to only "B4:C" and .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B") maintained on B for the Grade but it doesn't seem to work, it considers the first column with the value rather than the amount column. How could I change that?

Comment: inputArray = .Range("B4:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value

Comment: And inputArray(currentItem, 4) > 0

Comment: QHarr, is it possible to use this code to instead of giving me only unique values from column A, gives me all the values within the rows from column A to D? if there is a number greater than 0 on column D (amount column).

The output could be in different rows for example: product 1 Range ("Y1") product 2 ("Y2")?

Comment: Load A:D into a 2d array from the sheet. Loop the 4th column and if > 0 ignore the row otherwise dump into a second array. Use a counter to keep track of the number of qualifying rows. Transpose the output (2nd) array, redim the rows which have become the columns to the counter, then transpose again so rows become rows again and write out to the sheet. If you post a new question I can show you but that is roughly how I would do it.

Comment: I'm really ashamed to say this but, all I was able to do is load A:D,by looping you mean change  inputArray2 = .Range("A4:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).Value ?

I tried many many times before replying to you. sorry =/

Comment: That’s ok. If you post a new question I will have a look and you may get a better answer from someone else.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear how you want to output your unique values. Do you want the entire row? Do you just want the values from `Column B`? *Where* do you want the output?

This is a straight forward way of doing this. You could also load the values into array given your criteria (`Amount > 0`) then loop through your array removing duplicates (plenty of solutions on how to do that on this site)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Unique()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim GradeRange As Range, Grade As Range, LRow As Long

LRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set GradeRange = ws.Range("B2:B" & LRow)

For Each Grade In GradeRange
    If Grade.Offset(, 2) > 0 Then
        Grade.Offset(, 3) = Grade
    End If
Next Grade

ws.Range("E2:E" & LRow).RemoveDuplicates 1

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi urdearboy, thank you so much for your help, I tried on searching for a solution before posting a question, im sorry if it have been asked many times.